# cakephp - How to handle integrity constraint violation errors

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Am at a loss here. I need to know how to handle error messages in case of integrity constraint violations.

Meaning i want to show users some meaningful message instead displaying error messages like

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I need to capture these databse errors and just show messages like say

```
The item you are trying to delete is associated with other records
```

How do we deal with this.

i have found a refernce here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8842963/576523

but i dont want to do a count check.

When we use the debug_kit plugin we can see that they have captured these values under the

variables tab. I need a way to do this or access these data from the debug_kit plugin.

Thankz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also use `try` - `catch`

```
try {
    $this->Item->delete();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = 'The item you are trying to delete is associated with other records';
    // The exact error message is $e->getMessage();
    $this->set('error', $error);
}
```

Comment: Thankz man... wow this was really simple enough!!! and i was searching all day long for this ... should have thought smarter...

Comment: If you are using CakePHP 3, the correct is the @Faisal anwser.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to catch a specific exception, specify the exception class in the catch block.Hope it will solve your problem.

```
try {
    $this->Item->delete();
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    $error = 'The item you are trying to delete is associated with other records';
    //exact error message $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using CAKEPHP3 -> [CakePHP 3 - Catch Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311368/cakephp-3-catch-error)

```
try
{}
catch (\PDOException $e)
{}
```

Solved like a charm ;) - \Exception or \PDOException