# CakePHP 2.x - delete cascade failed, instead going to error -> showing a message

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a table with several dependent assocciations. When I try to delete a record from the parent table it goes in sql error because it has child records. And it's ok because I don't want to delete the record if it has dependents but instead of going to error I want to show a message.

Is there any way to do this without doing a query first to check if it has dependents?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: ... and Cake rocks

Comment: Read this [cakephp - How to handle integrity constraint violation errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300127/cakephp-how-to-handle-integrity-constraint-violation-errors)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was quick and clear