# CakePHP 3 - Catch Error

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-3.0

```
use Cake\Core\Exception\Exception;


for($i=1; $i<count($values); $i++) {
        $entity = $table->newEntity();

        // irrelevant code

        try {
            $table->save($entity);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $errors[$i-1] = $values[$i];
        } finally {
            if(count($errors) == 0)
                $this->Flash->success('All rows are successfully imported. ');
            else {
                $this->Flash->error('Not all rows are successfully imported. ');
                debug($errors);
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is catch the conflicted entities and show these to the user.

What I get is an PDO exception. The ones that don't conflict are still inserted, what I want.

So I only want to catch the PDO exception, but how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch Exception in Cakephp 3 : not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569444/catch-exception-in-cakephp-3-not-working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to catch a specific exception, specify the exception class in the catch block.

```
try
{}
catch (\PDOException $e)
{}
```

Comment: I know, but that's not the problem in my case. Already did that.

Comment: what you exactly want to do?

Comment: @dnns You did that and probably forgot the leading namespace separator, just like Gerd did. `PDOException` lives in the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks indeed. Solved by '\'.

Comment: Since yesterday i have been facing same problem. Have been trying try{}catch(PDOException $e) with leading  \ or not. Don't get any result.

Comment: So it's either not a PDOException or it is an exception with the same name but in a different namespace.The leading slash means that it catches the PDOException in the global namespace.